# iPhone Text Field

Tags: iphone, nsstring, textfield, exponent

I have run into an issue that I have yet to be able to solve.   Hopefully someone can help. I have an app that I am using to do simple calculations, some of the results are larger than the UItextField.  Does anyone know how to limit the output to say 10 characters like say a calculator would using exponents.  This is the code I am using currently.

myVar.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2.1", myVar]

This just limits the decimal place. The 2 in front of the decimal does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way. Hope this helps

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 20

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length >= MAX_LENGTH && range.length == 0)
    {
        return NO; // return NO to not change text
    }
    else
    {return YES;}
}
```

ref: [Set the maximum character length of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield)

Comment: This is usefull code.  It only limits input from key pad though.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1). Sounds like you want *1.2E* or _1.2_e.

Comment: This write all output in scientific notation.  Not all needs to appear that way.  Only if over a certain length.

Comment: Check the length of the output then, and only convert if it's longer than your preference.