# Cocoa Touch UITextField first character uppercase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextField.
How can I make sure that the first character is uppercase?

I tried this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
if (newLength == 1) {
    string = [string uppercaseString];
}

return YES;

}
```

But even after uppercasing the string, it is still lower case.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the maximum character length of a UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I got it.
There is the capitalize option in Interface Builder.

Thanks,
Tee