# Limit number of characters in uitextview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I am giving a text view to tweet some string .

I am applying the following method to restrict the number of characters to 140 in length.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
   return [[textView text] length] <= 140;
}
```

The code is working nicely except the first condition that backspace is not working.
 suppose that  I have reached the limit of 140 characters so that the method will give me false and the user can not insert more characters but after that when I try to delete some characters the text view behave as it is disabled .

So the question is: "How to delete characters from `textview.text` or re-enable the text view?"

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/433337/1603234)

Comment: @Hemang http://stackoverflow.com/a/41380869/2910061

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should be looking for an empty string instead, as the [apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) says

> If the user presses the Delete key, the length of the range is 1 and an empty string object replaces that single character.

I think the check you actually want to make is something like `[[textView text] length] - range.length + text.length > 140`, to account for cut/paste operations.

Comment: thanks but can be more specific I can not understand the technical specification of apple

Comment: just tell me what should I put in the first condition . I am gooling for this for almost 4 hours

Comment: I think the check you actually want to make is something like `[[textView text] length] - range.length + text.length > 140`, to account for cut/paste operations.

Comment: [[textView text] length] - range.length + text.length > 140 should be [[textView text] length] - range.length + text.length < 140

Comment: Kuzon, not if you are returning true as default and want to return false if you exceed the 140 char limit.

Comment: In this case, you will count also the new line ... I would prefer something like this:   NSMutableString *newString = [textView.text mutableCopy];
    [newString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    
    if ( [newString length] <= 140) { ....
if you dont want to count the new line you can simply manipulate newString ....

Answer (score 179):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    return textView.text.length + (text.length - range.length) <= 140;
}
```

This accounts for users cutting text, or deleting strings longer than a single character (ie if they select and then hit backspace), or highlighting a range and pasting strings shorter or longer than it.

Swift 4.0 Version

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return textView.text.count + (text.count - range.length) <= 140
}
```

Comment: is this an IBAction? how do I connect it to the TextView in question as user types?

Comment: Gotta make your view controller a UITextViewDelegate and then hook up file's owner as the text view's delegate

Comment: I thought it would be more fair to ask a follow up question: I am having issues with having two UITextviews that need character limits in the same controller. Will you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272413/limit-number-of-characters-user-may-inter-into-multiple-uitextviews

Comment: This should be marked as the correct response. Thank you

Comment: This will cause a crash if you paste a text that is too long to fit (therefore `false` will be returned) and then you will try to undo the action.

Answer (score 19):

for swift 4:

```
//MARK:- TextView Delegate
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    //300 chars restriction
    return textView.text.count + (text.count - range.length) <= 300
}
```

Answer (score 10):

However you can use below working code also..

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSInteger restrictedLength=140;

    NSString *temp=textView.text;

    if([[textView text] length] > restrictedLength){
        textView.text=[temp substringToIndex:[temp length]-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally not the preferred way to edit something after it has been set. Better checking this in "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" to prevent text from being edited.

Answer (score 10):

#### Limit the overflow, not the entire text!

By returning `false` in the `...shouldChangeTextInRange...` delegate method, you are actually limiting the entire text and handling the following situations could be so hard:

- Copy and pasting
- Select an area of the text and edit
- Using auto-suggest
- Using voice input (voice command or dictation)

So you can:

### Just limit the text-overflow!

By removing extra characters:

```
textView.text = String(textView.text.prefix(140))
```

You can do it even **on the fly**! by putting this code inside the **action** of the `textView` or `textField` with the `.editingChanged` event.

Comment: Placing this in the UITextView delegate's `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {...}` works beautifully, only cropping the end of a long pasted text

Answer (score 7):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12, try the following implementation of [`textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview) method that is part of the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    guard let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textView.text) else {
        return false
    }
    let substringToReplace = textView.text[rangeOfTextToReplace]
    let count = textView.text.count - substringToReplace.count + text.count
    return count <= 10
}
```

- The most important part of this code is the conversion from `range` (`NSRange`) to `rangeOfTextToReplace` (`Range<String.Index>`). See this [video tutorial](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E80-swift-string-vs-nsstring?t=6) to understand why this conversion is important.
- To make this code work properly, you should also set the `textField`'s [`smartInsertDeleteType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2865828-smartinsertdeletetype) value to `UITextSmartInsertDeleteType.no`. This will prevent the possible insertion of an (unwanted) extra space when performing a paste operation.

---

The complete sample code below shows how to implement `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` in a `UIViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView! // Link this to a UITextView in Storyboard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.smartInsertDeleteType = UITextSmartInsertDeleteType.no
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        guard let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textView.text) else {
            return false
        }
        let substringToReplace = textView.text[rangeOfTextToReplace]
        let count = textView.text.count - substringToReplace.count + text.count
        return count <= 10
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift:

```
// MARK: UITextViewDelegate

let COMMENTS_LIMIT = 255

func textView(textView: UITextView,  shouldChangeTextInRange range:NSRange, replacementText text:String ) -> Bool {
    return count(comments.text) + (count(text) - range.length) <= COMMENTS_LIMIT;
}
```

Comment: `countElements` has been replaced by `count` in swift 1.2

Comment: and in Swift 2 you have to to 
    textView.text.characters.count 
or whatever encoding you want: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30

Answer (score 4):

ue this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    int limit = 139;

    return !([textField.text length]>limit && [string length] > range.length);

}
```

this will only enter 140 char and you can delete them if need

Answer (score 2):

Though I needed an `if-else` condition, so this worked for me:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    BOOL status = textView.text.length + (text.length - range.length) <= 15;
    if (status)
    {
        [self.btnShare setEnabled:YES];
        [self.btnShare setAlpha:1];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.btnShare setEnabled:NO];
        [self.btnShare setAlpha:0.25];
    }
    return status;
}
```

Intially the button is set to disabled. But if you want user cant post an empty test, simply put a condition on button click:

```
- (void)btnShare_click:(id)sender
{
    NSString *txt = [self.txtShare.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([txt length] == 0)
    {
        [self.btnShare setEnabled:NO];
        [self.btnShare setAlpha:0.25f];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please enter some text to share." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:-

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    print("chars \(textView.text.count) \( text)")

    if(textView.text.count > 20 && range.length == 0) {
        print("Please summarize in 20 characters or less")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem with some of the answer given above is, For example I have a text field and I have to set a limit of 15 characters input, then it stops after entering 15th Character. but they Don't allow to delete. That is the delete button also don't work. As I was facing the same problem. Came out with the solution , Given Below. Works Perfect for Me

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 if(textField.tag==6)
 {
    if ([textField.text length]<=30)
    {
        return YES;   
    }
    else if([@"" isEqualToString:string])
    {
        textField.text=[textField.text substringToIndex:30 ];
    }

    return NO;
 }
 else
 {
    return YES;
 }
}
```

I am having a text field, whose tag I have set "6"
and I have restricted the max char limit = 30 ;
works fine in every case

Answer (score 1):

@Tim Gostony 's Swift Version:

```
// restrict the input for textview to 500
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return count(textView.text) + (count(text) - range.length) <= 500;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go for best fit.
Display number of characters left: 'n' characters left.

```
var charCount = 0;
let maxLength = 150
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if text == "" // Checking backspace
    {
        if textView.text.characters.count == 0
        {
            charCount = 0
            characterCount.text = String(format: "%i Characters Left", maxLength - charCount)
            return false
        }
        charCount = (textView.text.characters.count - 1)
        characterCount.text = String(format: "%i Characters Left", maxLength - charCount)
      return true
    }
    else
    {
        charCount = (textView.text.characters.count + 1)
        characterCount.text = String(format: "%i Characters Left", maxLength - charCount)

        if charCount >= maxLength + 1
        {
            charCount = maxLength
            characterCount.text = String(format: "%i Characters Left", maxLength - charCount)
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're also looking to be able to paste code up to the max character count, while cutting off overflow, and updating a count label:

```
let maxChar: Int
let countLabel: UILabel

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let oldChar = textView.text.count - range.length
    let oldRemainingChar = maxChar - oldChar
    let newChar = oldChar + text.count
    let newRemainingChar = maxChar - newChar
    let replaceChar = newRemainingChar > 0 ? text.count : oldRemainingChar

    if
        let textRange = textView.textRange(for: range),
        replaceChar > 0 || range.length > 0
    {
        textView.replace(textRange, withText: String(text.prefix(replaceChar)))
        countLabel.text = String(describing: maxChar - textView.text.count)
    }

    return false
}
```

With the extension:

```
extension UITextInput {
    func textRange(for range: NSRange) -> UITextRange? {
        var result: UITextRange?

        if
            let start = position(from: beginningOfDocument, offset: range.location),
            let end = position(from: start, offset: range.length)
        {
            result = textRange(from: start, to: end)

        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method :

```
if ([textView.text length]>=3 && ![text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if(self.txtViewComments.text.length > 255)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: if condition is used for deleting characters from the text view

Answer (score 0):

**Swift5:**

```
let maxChars = 255

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
  if maxChars - aTextView.text.count == 0 {
    if range.length != 1 {
    return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution for restricting user to enter number of character in `UITextField` or in `UITextView` in iOS swift

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
{
   return textField.text!.count < limit ? true : false
}
```

Note: here limit can be anything from `1` to `n` as per your requirement, for e.g: if you working on phone number than `limit` value will be `10`
if you want to apply same on `UITextView` just method will be change and at the place of `textfield` you will be use `textview`