# limit number of characters user may enter into multiple UITextViews

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

In some sense this question has already been answered at [Limit number of characters in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492247/limit-number-of-characters-in-uitextview). But my particular case is that I have more than one textview in the same ViewController. So I am not sure how to fix that problem. Say I only have two textViews. How might I handle these cases:

- they both have the same character limit?
- each has different character limit? say 300 and 400 respectively.

Do I use `IBAction`? If yes how?

Comment: It's basically the same answer. Just use the `textView` property to test which text view is being processed.

Comment: @rmaddy I like when the answers to my **BIG** questions are so simple. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need IBOutlet for both textviews

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield2;
```

then in your delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

You simply add a check for the right textfield

```
if (self.textfield1 == textfield) {
// handle first text field here

} else {
// handle second text field here
}
```

Comment: If you didn't want to keep the textViews as properties for whatever reason, you could also use tags. `textView1.tag = 1; textView2.tag = 2; if (textView.tag == 1) { // do something } else { // do something else }`