# Limit number of characters in uitextview - I have 5 text view same page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have five textview in same page. But just one textview editable. i wanna limit this textview characters. 
I use  `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` but it didn't work.
My `UITextView` reference name is  UserNote.
I try `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)UserNote` 
Unfortunately did not work again.
Please help me. Thanks.
I Change My reference Name it is textView now.

My Code  ;

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSUInteger length;
    length = [textView.text length];

    NSString * last = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", 160 - length];

    [_characterLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",last]];

    NSLog(@"%@" , last);
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    // Prevent crashing undo bug – see note below.
    if(range.length + range.location > textView.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 160) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: did you set the delegate to your textview ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit number of characters in uitextview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492247/limit-number-of-characters-in-uitextview)

Comment: you can set a tag to each textView and in delegate method you can write: if(textView.tag == 0) //0 is an example you should put the number of tag of editable textview...

Comment: Show the code you used and tell us what "did not work" means.  (That is, what happened that was different from what you wanted.)

Comment: i try with tag. Didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in these methods, does it hit the breakpoint? If not, set your textview's delegate. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: My project is working. Just - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView methods didnt work. I use NSLog in this method and edit textView but i didnt see my log message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it. Just i forgot setup UITextView Delegate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This expression it's good

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

NSString *string = [[textView text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

if ([string length] > 60)
{
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```