# Set the maximum text size for NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

ALL,

All posts here on SO and Google points to a way of doing it for NSTextField. I need it for a NSTextView.

I am developing cross-platform application where I will need an NSTextView, not a Field, whose data will go into the DB field whose size is limited to 255 characters.

So I would rather prevent the user of the application to enter more than 255 characters, than unexpectedly cut the text o the DB insert.

I know the class don't have anythihg built-in, but maybe there is a way to make it work somehow.

TIA!!

EDIT:

I tried to implement the suggested method, but failed.

Here is what I did:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    [super shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:text];
    // code to check the number of characters
}
```

I got following error/warning:

```
warning: instance method '-shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:' not found
      (return type defaults to 'id') [-Wobjc-method-access]
    [super shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementText:text];
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/NSTextView.h:64:12: note: 
      receiver is instance of class declared here
@interface NSTextView : NSText <NSUserInterfaceValidations, NSTextInputClient, NSTextLayoutOrientationProvider, NSDraggingSource, NSText...
           ^
1 warning generated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I do see that function in the NSTextView...

Comment: Have you tried implementing delegate method `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementString:)`? It's similar to [Limit number of characters in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492247/limit-number-of-characters-in-uitextview)

Comment: @Willeke, thx for the pointer. However according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview?language=objc its available since 10.13.Anything from 10.10?

Comment: And another question - what is the connection between UITextView and NSTextView?

Comment: `UITextView` is iOS, `NSTextView` is macOS.

Comment: `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` (`NSTextViewDelegate`) is available since Mac OS X 10.0. `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` (`UITextViewDelegate`) is available since iOS 2.0 and Mac Catalyst 13.0.

Comment: @Willeke, please check my edit. Thx for the help.

Comment: The difference between `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` (`NSTextViewDelegate`) and `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` (`UITextViewDelegate`) is in the last parameter `replacementString`/`replacementText`.

Comment: Implementing a `NSTextViewDelegate` merhod is not the same as overriding a `NSTextView` method. Don't call `super`.

Comment: @Willeke, I shouldn't call `super` for the delegate or when overriding?

Comment: @Willeke, also, I overrode the function, but when I ran it thru the debugger, the code didn't stop there... Is it because I name the parameter wrong?

Comment: `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` isn't a `NSTextViewDelegate` method so it is not called.

Comment: @Willeke, I'm trying to override this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449532-shouldchangetextinrange?language=objc. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [Limit number of characters in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492247/limit-number-of-characters-in-uitextview) and adapted to `NSTextViewDelegate`, implement in the delegate of the text view:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)affectedCharRange 
    replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString {
    return textView.string.length + (replacementString.length - affectedCharRange.length) <= 140;   
}
```

The same trick in a subclass of `NSTextView`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)affectedCharRange 
    replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString {
    return [super shouldChangeTextInRange:affectedCharRange replacementString:replacementString] &&
        (self.string.length + (replacementString.length - affectedCharRange.length) <= 140);    
}
```

Comment: the subclass works, but partially. It handles the cse with the typing characters by character and it handles the case when I paste the text if the total number of chars is less. But what I also want is to check the pasted text and paste partial if I cam't paste the full text. Lets say I have a limit of 20. I currently have 10 characters and trying to paste 20. I want first 10 chars to be pasted and the last 10 dropped.

Comment: @Igor That's a new question.

Comment: done. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523943/paste-the-text-on-osx-with-maximum-number-of-charcters. Thx.

Comment: I tried to implement what I wanted but failed. Could you please look at my edit to the question above? Thx.