# Set UITextField Maximum Length

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, max

Is there any way to set the maximum length on a UITextField?

Something like the MAXLENGTH attribute in HTML input fields.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

This works correctly with backspace and copy & paste:

```
#define MAXLENGTH 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
    NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
    NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

    NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

    BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

    return newLength <= MAXLENGTH || returnKey;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Updated to accept the return key even when at MAXLENGTH. Thanks Mr Rogers!

Comment: This answer is the only one that actually works when the user tries to paste in a long string. Please upvote!

Comment: This answer works perfectly. The accepted answer does not work, as the user can enter one more character than MAXLENGTH.

Comment: If they're pasting, should it not paste up until they hit the limit?

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin I don't think that's possible. This API only allows us to say YES or NO to the entire block of text.

Comment: Could you set the textfield.text to however much you can before returning NO?

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin I wouldn't do that because I don't think it is a correct way to use this API but you can certainly try it.

Comment: I had a problem where the Done key wouldn't get registered if I was already at `MAXLENGTH`.  I had to look for newline characters if at `MAXLENGTH` and return `YES` still.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome answer. It would be great if there was a way to make this a subclass, category, or SOMETHING, so that one never had to do this again.  It would have to allow for setting the length, individually, for each text field in a project.

Comment: Small suggestion for performance: do not put the returnKey check in a separate bool. Now you are checking for a return although most of the time newLength will be smaller than MAXLENGTH. Remove the BOOL line and replace the last line with: `return newLength <= maxLength || ([string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound);`

Comment: Not work for Chinese chracters input

Answer (score 41):

**UPDATE**

I cannot delete this answer because it is the accepted one, but it was not correct. Here is the correct code, copied from TomA below:

```
#define MAXLENGTH 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
    NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
    NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

    NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

    BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

    return newLength <= MAXLENGTH || returnKey;
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

I think you mean UITextField.  If yes, then there is a simple way.

1. Implement the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol
2. Implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.

That method gets called on every character tap or previous character replacement.  in this method, you can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > MAXLENGTH) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH-1];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes I was meaning UITextField, I edited my question.

I got it. Thanks for your answer. It works for me !

Comment: You also need to assign the proper delegate to de UITextField.

Comment: This is somewhat flawed: 1) by checking the existing field text length (and not the proposed new length) you allow the user to go 1 character beyond the maximum, and 2) it doesn't prevent users from copy-and-pasting more text in.

Comment: It should be `>= MAXLENGTH` and `substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH`.

Comment: Your code sample does not work on iOS 5 (MAXLENGTH = 5). I can enter 6 characters. When I try to enter another character, it removes the 6th character. My correction in the comment above does not completely fix the problem either. TomA's answer works perfectly.

Comment: This solution is quite bad.. if you set maxlength to 2 you can actually enter 6 characters. Also nothing happens when you press the backspace button on the keyboard. and thirdly, when keep typing, it will replace the previous string. Please see this answer, which works much better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield

Comment: This old answer was never meant to be a copy/paste job, but a place to show you where to hook in the custom logic you can determine for your own app. You will be a much better engineer when someone shows you how to solve the problem instead of giving you the answer.

Answer (score 17):

A better function which handles backspaces correctly and limits the characters to the supplied length limit is the following:

```
#define MAXLENGTH 8

    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        int length = [textField.text length] ;
        if (length >= MAXLENGTH && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: I believe you dont need to substring the textfield

Comment: This one doesn't prevent the length going over the maximum when the user pastes a string that is longer than the maximum.

Answer (score 12):

This code limits the text while also allowing you enter characters or paste anywhere into the text. If the resulting text would be too long it changes the characters in the range and truncates the resulting text to the limit.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] - range.length + [string length];
    if (newLength >= MAXLENGTH) {
        textField.text = [[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this code would do the trick:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
                                                       replacementString:(NSString*)string
{
   if (range.location >= MAX_LENGTH)
      return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

With this delegate method you can prevent the user to add more characters than MAX_LENGTH to your text field and the user should be allowed to enter backspaces if needed.

Comment: This doesn't fully cover the case where the user is pasting; it allows the string to become too long.

Answer (score 2):

For me this did the magic:

```
if (textField.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0)
    return NO;
return YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how i resolved that problem. When max limit is reached it wont try to add more... you will only be able to remove chars

```
#define MAX_SIZE ((int) 5)
...

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] >= MAX_SIZE && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no such property.

But the text you assign to the UILabel has to be an NSString. And before you assign this string to the UILabel's text property you can for example use the following method of NSString to crop the string at a given index (your maxlength):

```
- (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex
```

Comment: Unfortunately the question asker changed their question after you answered, so your answer no longer makes any sense :(

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to coneybeare's answer, but now the text field can contain a maximum of MAXLENGTH symbols:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > MAXLENGTH - 1) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This one doesn't prevent the length going over the maximum when the user pastes a string longer than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware of the location the text is placed in as well as the length of text being added (in case they're pasting more than one character). The pattern between these with respect to max length is that their sum should never exceed the max length.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSInteger locationAndStringLengthSum = range.location + [string length];

    if ([textField isEqual:_expirationMonthField]) {
        if (locationAndStringLengthSum > EXP_MONTH_FIELD_MAX_CHAR_LENGTH) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:_expirationYearField]) {
        if (locationAndStringLengthSum > EXP_YEAR_FIELD_MAX_CHAR_LENGTH) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:_securityCodeField]) {
        if (locationAndStringLengthSum > SECURITY_FIELD_MAX_CHAR_LENGTH) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else if ([textField isEqual:_zipCodeField]) {
        if (locationAndStringLengthSum > ZIP_CODE_MAX_CHAR_LENGTH) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to assign delegate on `ViewDidLoad`

```
TextFieldname.delegate=self
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Implementation of the delegate would be more interesting.