# Set custom UITextField max length

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I can't find a solution on my problem because all other posts at [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523501/set-uitextfield-maximum-length) refer to UITextField created with the IDE and not programmatically.

I have a custom `UITextField` created inside  `(void)viewDidLoad`.I have this created programmatically so i can access the `leftView` property.

```
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 66, screenAdj, 30)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    textField.text=[defaults stringForKey:@"username"];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    label.text = @"Your name";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textField.leftView = label;
```

I also want to limit the max characters inside the TextField implementing:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
    NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
    NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

    NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

    BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

    return newLength <= MAX_LENGTH_USERNAME || returnKey;
}
```

But i realized that my textField doesn't "see" the above function.Tried with

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(...
```

but no luck.
Any help?

Comment: why did you cut of the most important piece of code after all? [tff addTarget:self action:@selector(changed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]; is the thing you need.

Comment: try textField.delegate = self; and the viewcontroller implemets shouldChangeCharactersInRange;

Comment: Jimpic it didn't work.But i got my solution,thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell your view controller to conform to UITextFields delegate protocol. In your (.h) add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` right after "UIViewController", and when you set up your text field set its delegate to `self`:

```
[textField setDelegate:self];
```

Then you can go ahead and remove this line

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(...
```

Assuming you were using this to call `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. Now that you've set up the delegate, this method will be called automatically.

Comment: It worked! I will accept this one in 5 minutes! Thank you all!