# Limit a NSMutablestring's length

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am working on a calculator App.
The `NSMutablestring` is used for calculation E.g `"5-3*8-(-1)/77"`.
But the label can't display endless an `NSMutablestring`, so is there have any way to limit `NSMutablestring`'s length?
(not too long, I want the `NSMutablestring`'s length to be less than 100).

Comment: Presumably entry is made using a `UITextField`, therefore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523501/set-uitextfield-maximum-length

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: Set Max Character length TextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first 100 characters of a string as follows:

```
NSString *first100chars = [myString substringToIndex:100];
```

However, it sounds like you need to prevent the user from actually entering a string this long, which is a different problem. The comments to your question give examples of other people asking similar questions (e.g. [Set the maximum character length of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield)), I suggest you check those.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for an NSFormatter subclass. That's exactly what it's for.