# Is there anyway to limit the number of character in UITextfield to 5?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Iam trying to limit the number of character in a textfield to 5 .So when we trying to enter the 6th character it will not do anything? is that possible .I saw below code but its not working .I have searched this in google got some results like

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 5) ? NO : YES;
}
```

its not working am still able to add more than 5 character

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set UITextField Maximum Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523501/set-uitextfield-maximum-length)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: Set Max Character length TextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your delegate connection with UITextfield

Comment: @Navi u r welcom navi

Answer (score 1):

Is the delegate being called? If YES, then just try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > 5) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:5-1];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```