# How to set character limit in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

In android all I have to do in the equivalent of "interface builder" is

```
 android:maxLines="140";//twitter's character limit
```

Is there an equivalently simple method for iOS?

Comment: Not exactly from IB but you can achieve same reuslt by doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield

Comment: max *lines* or max *characters*?  Twitter can obviously not be 140 lines unless there is only one character per line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UITextFieldDelegate to listen the length of input, you can see this [uitextfield-maximun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523501/set-uitextfield-maximum-length)

also you need adapt the protocol and set the delegate to your textfield.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 140;

NSString *displaySTR = ......
if ([displaySTR length] > n) {
displaySTR = [string substringToIndex:n];
}
```