# UITextFields firstResponder problem

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

hello all i am working with multiple uitextfields.i have a problem in cursor placing while changing firstResponder. i would like to do "Cursor placement in 2nd field once we entered the 3rd character in the 1st field." but the cursor stays in 3rd place.here i am restricting my first text field length to 3.

Answer (score 1):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield/433468#433468) should help you. You set up notifications to be issued when the first text field state changes, firing a method that checks the text field's length. If `firstTextField.text.length` is equal to three characters, call `[secondTextField becomeFirstResponder]`.

Comment: But it is working in isolated project.When i combine this to my project its not working.why?

Comment: k its solved friend.i forget to call the awakeFromNib in my viewDidLoad.Thank u very much for the quick response

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please press the ✔ next to it.