# How to put a character limit on a UITextField

Tags: xcode, nsstring, uitextfield, limit, character

I would like to put a character limit on a UITextField but don't know how. I want it to have a maximum of 16 characters in it. How do I do this.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/433337/1603234)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 12) ? NO : YES;
}
```