# textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString vs. UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm building a Passcode Lock view, and I want to set the text to a dot on one of the four box labels when a user enters a new character into the text field.

Should I use [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield/1773257#1773257) or [UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield/433468#433468)?

Using textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString seems easier, but shouldChangeCharactersInRange seems more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d recommend using the delegate method, rather than the notification.
Another option: set the text fields’ `secureTextEntry` property to YES. (See the [documentation for the UITextInputTraits protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html), which UITextField conforms to).