# How to stop entering value in UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

How to stop entering value in UITextField if the length is greater then 20 char.

Programmatically.

Comment: cant you use Javascript?

Comment: i dont know javascript. is it possible in objective-c validation. so i cant enter the  values in UITextField if the length is equal to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    //Set tag for a textfield
    if(textField.tag==10)
    {
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return (newLength > 20) ? NO : YES;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the delegate method... with the logic..... its really helps a lot to stop entering the range.

Answer (score 0):

[Set the maximum character length of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield)