# How to set limit in text field?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

can any body tell me how to set the limit for words to enter in a text field in objective-c?
In my case i have a registration form and in registration form every user have to enter `username`, `password`, `email` and `phone no.` and now i have to restrict the user to enter a name of maximum 15 characters.

can any one tell me how i can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: Set Max Character length TextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield)

Comment: This post likely has what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to restrict number of inputs in `UITextField` both following ways.

First of all, set relevant `UIViewController` as a delegate object to `UITextField`

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Then add the following code snippet to your `UIViewController`.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length]<15) {
           return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Or you can define `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in your `UIViewController` interface

```
@interface YourViewController()<UITextFieldDelegate>
  // YourViewController.m
@end
```

and then implement the following `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` task in your class.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
   return (newLength > 15) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong as it will consider the length before the text field's text changes as a result of user typing and not what it would be. Check the question which has been marked as duplicate for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSString *textFieldText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        if ([textFieldText length] > 15) 
        {
            return NO;
        }

 return YES;
}
```