# How to limit the amount of characters in 5 UITextFields

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone SDK: Set Max Character length TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield)

I have 5 UITextFields, where only 6 characters should be allowed. How can I limit the input to just 6 characters per text field? Any other code I tried failed and I didn't found a way of fixing it, thanks :D
**EDIT:** This is the codes I tested:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger newLength1 = [serie1.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSUInteger newLength2 = [serie2.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSUInteger newLength3 = [serie3.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSUInteger newLength4 = [serie4.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSUInteger newLength5 = [serie5.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    if(newLength1 > 6)
        return NO;
    if(newLength2 > 6)
        return NO; 
    if(newLength3 > 6)
        return NO; 
    if(newLength4 > 6)
        return NO; 
    if(newLength5 > 6)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

and

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(serie1.text.length >= 6 && range.length == 0) {
        return NO;

    }
    if(serie2.text.length >= 6 && range.length == 0) {
        return NO;

    }
    if(serie3.text.length >= 6 && range.length == 0) {
        return NO;

    }
    if(serie4.text.length >= 6 && range.length == 0) {
        return NO;

    }
    if(serie5.text.length >= 6 && range.length == 0) {
        return NO;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Both have the problem that when you write 6 characters then you cannot write anymore on any other text field until you delete the characters you wrote

Comment: I guess not, because I already saw that and tried it without luck

Comment: Then please provide code of what you have tried, because that is the logic used by many developers since iOs developement started..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if(textField.text.length >= 7 && range.length == 0)  
   {
      return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Whoops nope, when I write 6 characters on a field, I can't write more on the next until I delete the 6 I wrote before

Comment: Nope, I tested this one and the next one, and nothing works, I'll post code on my question, hold on

Comment: please set delegate for all textfields. and you have not need t write for all text fields ..my code will work, copy past as it is and set delegate in nib for all text fields..

Comment: already set them via code and via ib

Comment: Ah thanks forgot about that, working now :D

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UITextField` Delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    if(newLength > 6)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```