# How to limit the characters of textfield in iOS application up to 5 characters?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I would like to limit the characters in `textField` of IOS Application. I tried all the methods given in Stack Overflow, so I am asking this question.

Here I used one Label (secure code) and one textfield (5 characters).

I had given the below code in `viewcontroller.m` file, but not working.

```
   myTextField.delegate = self

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

{
   NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

   return !([newString length] > 5);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/iphone-sdk-set-max-character-length-textfield

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **ViewController.h**, `<UITextFieldDelegate>` should be added.

In your viewDidLoad, `myTextField.delegate = self` should be added.

And then, to limit the number of characters:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     if (textField.text.length >= 5 && range.length == 0)
        return NO;
     return YES;
}
```

Works for me. Try it.

**EDIT:**

On the other hand, your code should work perfectly fine as well. Check your code again.

Comment: I worked with this code. one issue is raised in ViewController.h file <UITextFieldDelegate> 'UITextFieldDelegate' not found. can U suggest me how to get out of this issue..

Comment: I added UIKit framework.my ViewContoller.m file is :                            [super viewDidLoad];
    txtsecurecode.delegate = self
    -(BOOL)txtsecurecode:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        return !([newString length] > 5);
    } }
error is in: -(BOOL) statement is "arithmetic on pointer to interface viewcontroller which is not a constant size in non-fragile abi".Can you help out to solve.

Comment: `-(BOOL)txtsecurecode:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` Change to `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

Comment: at the point of -(BOOL)textField  issue: "use of UnDelacared identifier'textField' " is raised. how to overcome this.

Comment: Okay. First up. Is your textfield linked as an IBOutlet? What is it called? Then put UITextFieldDelegate like this `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`. Next, you seem to have put `myTextField.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad, which is fine. **myTextField** should be your textfield name. Then add the method you have put up in the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24416/discussion-between-sudheer-chekuri-and-blackflam3)

Answer (score 0):

In swift: add `UITextFieldDelegate` as an `extension`. It makes your job easier.

Don't forget to set textField's `delegate` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set the delegate
    textField.delegate = self
}

extension ViewController:UITextFieldDelegate {
  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.text?.characters.count >= 5 && range.length == 0 {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

You can find a detailed example how to limit textfield by `count` and `width`:
[github source](https://github.com/fatihyildizhan/Limit-Textfields-s-Text)