# How to limit text length for a textfield in a UIAlert iOS.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

How would I limit the amount of text, that can be entered in a text field in a UIAlertView with my existing code?

I am new to iOS app development.

My code is as following:

```
if(indexPath.row== 1){
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Enter Novena Day"
                              message:@"Please enter the day of Novena:"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

    [alertView show];

}
```

Comment: Implement the delegate of the text field, and implement code that checks how many characters there are and disallows any more than allowed.

Comment: You limit it like you would for any other text field.

Comment: So I would be able to use a typical delegation for the text field?

Comment: @LeoNatan Really? Don't down vote a question just because the wrong tag is used, especially with a new user. Down vote for proper reasons such as an obvious lack of effort to research an answer first or failing to provide enough detail to provide help.

Comment: Is this correct way to delegate a textfield [textField setDelegate:shouldChangeCharactersInRange];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize the alert view:

```
[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
```

Now, `self` here is your view controller. So you need to add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to its declaration.

Now implement the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > self.maxAlertTextFieldLength) ? NO : YES;
}
```

This is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield), linked answer in the comments.

Comment: There is an issue that has cropped up maxAlertTextFieldLength not found on object of type ViewController.

Comment: @JohnDoherty It's not found because you need to define a property and set it to the number of characters that you want to allow. My code is an example.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to better use a notification

check this

```
UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldMaxLimit:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];


-(void)textFieldMaxLimit:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  UITextField *textField=(UITextField*)notification.object;

        if ([[textField text] length]>22) //choose your limit for characters
        {
            NSString *lastString=[[textField text] substringToIndex:[[textField text] length] - 1];;
            [textField setText:lastString];
        }
 }
```

Comment: This approach is far from ideal and in fact doesn't work if the user pastes in a bunch of text (since you assume 1 character at a time). It's better to prevent the text from being added at all then adjusting it after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate , check your condition and return the desired value.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

  BOOL isValid = YES;

  @try
  {
     if(5 < [textField.text length])
     {
        isValid = NO;
     }
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception)
  {
     NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
  }
  @finally
  {
     return isValid;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I am delegating correctly, would you be able to check   `        [textField setDelegate:shouldChangeCharactersInRange];`