# Limit number of characters for a UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm creating a text input uialertview using the method below.

```
[dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
```

How can I limit the number of characters the user is able to input?

Comment: You can use `textfield` delegate methods

Comment: user `textfield delegate` and add this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

First add `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
UIAlertView *dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]init];// Setup your alert 
[dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0].placeholder = @"";//add this if you need
[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
```

and add textfield delegate as per [Check this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 25) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Please always provide the supported link on the top of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have instance of your alertView just do the following

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if([self.alertView textFieldAtIndex:0])
    {
      NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
      return (newLength > 25) ? NO : YES;
    }
    return YES; // suppress warning about control reaching end of non-void function
}
```