# how to limit uitextfield character range upto 10 digit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I just want to know how to limit uitextfield range, i.e I have one textbox in that I enter values 10 digit. If I try to type more than 10 digit my textfield should not accept the values. To be very simple I want only 10 digit should be enter in the textfield.

I work out this code but its not worked for me:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

return newLength <= MAXLENGTH || returnKey;
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the maximum character length of a UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield)

Comment: [This][1] is the best solution I found. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 11):

To limit a text input's length implement this method of UITextFieldDelegate and check a text's length after changing:

```
- (BOOL)            textField:(UITextField *)textField
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
            replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *resultText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                   withString:string];
    return resultText.length <= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> In Swift 3.0

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let charsLimit = 10

    let startingLength = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    let lengthToAdd = string.characters.count
    let lengthToReplace =  range.length
    let newLength = startingLength + lengthToAdd - lengthToReplace

    return newLength <= charsLimit
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below  code that is restricted to 10 digital text.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

        NSInteger length = [textField.text length];
        if (length>9 && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
            return NO;
        }

        // This code will provide protection if user copy and paste more then 10 digit text

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           if ([textField.text length]>10) {
                textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:10];

            }
       });


        return YES;
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: What the reason to checking this:  ![string isEqualToString:@""] ?

Comment: it will allow to edit once you backspace click. means after adding 10 digit its allowed to edit that digits

Comment: It is clever to allow user to paste a big string and then crop it. May be useful. Thanks for approach.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 Version

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
        if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
            return false
        }
        let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
        return newLength <= 10
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
{
    return NO;
}

NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return (newLength > 10) ? NO : YES;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this...i hope it will help you/

```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
       int lenght1 = code.text.length - range.length + string.length;
    if (textField.text.length >= 4 && range.length == 0)
          return NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a really nice subclass of `UITextField` to limit the number of characters inputted into a field. Here you go!:

```
public class NumberFormattedTextField : UITextField {
    @IBInspectable public var maximumCharacters = 10 {
         didSet {
             format()
        }
    }

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
         format()
         addTarget(self, action: "format", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
    }

    func format() {
         let len = text.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
         // truncate for max characters if needed
         if len > maximumCharacters {
             text = text[1...maximumCharacters] // pulls in the last entered character and drops the first one off to preserve length
         }
    }
}
```

This depends on a subscript for `String`. Here's that too:

```
public extension String {
    public subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String? {
        let l = self.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if r.startIndex <= l && r.endIndex <= l {
            return substringWithRange(Range(start: advance(startIndex, r.startIndex), end: advance(startIndex, r.endIndex)))
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have build a subclass based on the answer given by [Oxcug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3259329/oxcug) without the need for creating an extension in String file and max characters length can be set from storyboard and from swift file as well.:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var maximumCharacters: Int = 80 {
        didSet {
            limitCharacters()
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        limitCharacters()
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomTextField.limitCharacters), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    func limitCharacters() {
        guard text != nil else {
            return
        }
        if (text?.characters.count)! > maximumCharacters {
            if let range = text?.index(before: (text?.endIndex)!) {
                text = text?.substring(to: range)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best Solution:**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        return range.location < 10 //Here 10 is your character limit
    }
```