# Create a rating view in IOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, rating

I want to create following rating views shown below. How is it possible to do it
[image]

I have got 3 conditions.I have got label in top and below that are stars and at the end there is TextField.  Good,Amazing,Horrific is set according to number of stars. When there is 1 Star i.e horrific condition we have to present four button Order issues, timing, friendliness,Cleanliness.And  `UITextField`  is shift below it

> I have implemented following code

```
#pragma mark -  Btn Action on start click

  - (IBAction)Btn_FirstHorrific:(id)sender {
       [self ReviewHorrific];
       [self NumOfStarWorstCase];

      str_deliveryBoyRating=@"1";
      str_customerComment=@"Horrific";
     }

- (IBAction)Btn_SecondNah:(id)sender {
       [self ReviewSecondNah];
       [self NumOfStarOthercase];

    str_deliveryBoyRating=@"2";
    str_customerComment=@"nah!";
     }

- (IBAction)Btn_ThirdItsOk:(id)sender {
    [self ReviewItsOk];
    [self NumOfStarOthercase];

    str_deliveryBoyRating=@"3";
    str_customerComment=@"Its ok";
    }

- (IBAction)Btn_FourthGood:(id)sender {
    [self ReviewGood];
    [self NumOfStarOthercase];

    str_deliveryBoyRating=@"4";
    str_customerComment=@"good";

    }

- (IBAction)Btn_FifthAmazing:(id)sender {
    [self ReviewAmazing];
    [self NumOfStarOthercase];

    str_deliveryBoyRating=@"5";
    str_customerComment=@"Amazing";


     }



#pragma mark - Change star colour in Number of star changes

- (void)ReviewHorrific{
    Btn_FirstHorrific.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);


    Btn_SecondNah.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    Btn_ThirdItsOk.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    Btn_FourthGood.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    Btn_FifthAmazing.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    lbl_report.text=@"Please report your issue";
    lbl_RateType.text=@"Horrific";

    self.View_WorstCase.hidden = FALSE;


    }


- (void)ReviewSecondNah{

    Btn_FirstHorrific.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_SecondNah.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);

    Btn_ThirdItsOk.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    Btn_FourthGood.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    Btn_FifthAmazing.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    lbl_report.text=@"Please report your issue";
    lbl_RateType.text=@"Nah!!";

  }

- (void)ReviewItsOk{

    Btn_FirstHorrific.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_SecondNah.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_ThirdItsOk.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);

    Btn_FourthGood.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    Btn_FifthAmazing.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    lbl_report.text=@"Please report your issue";
    lbl_RateType.text=@"It's OK";

}

- (void)ReviewGood{

    Btn_FirstHorrific.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_SecondNah.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_ThirdItsOk.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_FourthGood.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);

    Btn_FifthAmazing.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    lbl_report.text=@"Heap praise if you would like";
    lbl_RateType.text=@"Good";

}

- (void)ReviewAmazing{

    Btn_FirstHorrific.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_SecondNah.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_ThirdItsOk.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_FourthGood.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);
    Btn_FifthAmazing.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8133);

    lbl_report.text=@"Glad to hear it. Any comments or feedback?";
    lbl_RateType.text=@"Amazing";

}
```

Comment: you can create the Five Buttons... please image view of Star on that..for design purpose

Comment: I have implemented that but i know my way is not best methods. and I have 3 different conditions so

Comment: try this, https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating/blob/master/DLStarRating.png , it provide valuechange method for your condition.

Comment: You can add two different images....1)when it is in normalState you can place unselectedStar images  2) and when it is selected you can please Yellow selected Star image. and tell me your conditions so that i can help you..

Comment: @nischalhada Is your problem solve or not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1)**

Add 5 `UIButton` to your UI file. Then in your header (.h) code, declare the `UIButton` like so:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *starOne;
IBOutlet UIButton *starTwo;
IBOutlet UIButton *starThree;
IBOutlet UIButton *starFour;
IBOutlet UIButton *starFive;
```

Then back in your UI file, link the star button views to your code. Then add the default (non-selected) star images to your buttons (just drag and drop to do this).

**Step 2)**

Back in your header code, add 5 `IBAction` methods. These will detect when the star buttons are pressed:

```
-(IBAction)press_1;
-(IBAction)press_2;
-(IBAction)press_3;
-(IBAction)press_4;
-(IBAction)press_5;
```

Then add a method as well. This method will handle the star images.

```
-(void)set_stars:(int)num :(NSString *)desc
```

Then declare in integer in your header file. This will tell you what the rating is, like so:

```
int rating;
```

Also declare an array (this will contain pointers to your star buttons):

```
NSArray *_starButtons;
```

Lastly, declare a `UILabel` to show the name for each rating (and like it to your UI), like so:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *rating_name;
```

**Step 3)**

In your implementation (.m) code, add in the following:

```
-(IBAction)press_1 {
    [self set_stars:1 :@"Horrific"];
}

-(IBAction)press_2 {
    [self set_stars:2 :@"nah!"];
}

-(IBAction)press_3 {
    [self set_stars:3 :@"Its ok"];
}

-(IBAction)press_4 {
    [self set_stars:4 :@"good"];
}

-(IBAction)press_5 {
    [self set_stars:5 :@"Amazing"];
}

 -(void)set_stars:(int)num :(NSString *)desc {

    rating_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", desc];

    for (int loop = 0; loop < 5; loop++) {

        if ((loop + 1) <= num) {
            [((UIButton*)_starButtons[loop]) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        else {
            [((UIButton*)_starButtons[loop]) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_OFF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

    rating = num;
 }
```

Finally, dont forget to populate the array with your buttons in the `viewDidLoad` method like so:

```
_starButtons = @[starOne, starTwo, starThree, starFour, starFive];
```

Comment: I have implemented similar type of action but It is long and tedious methods so i want to change it. I want to do every thing inside one action rather then multiple. ca you help me out

Comment: @nischalhada Yeah I am just working on a better for loop version. I will update my answer in a min.

Comment: Ok I will be waiting for that

Comment: Ok I will try to implement and check it

Comment: can you help me out for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796503/how-to-enable-the-uitextfield-to-have-only-one-text-number/29796807#29796807

Comment: @nischalhada I have updated my answer to include the rating label too :)

Comment: I got some confusion I will try to implement it next day and will mention about it to u

Comment: @nischalhada thanks for the tick. I take it, that my solution worked for you in the end or at least worked more or less for you?

Comment: @nischalhada I thought that question has been answered already?

Comment: I m unable to post questions coz of negative marking can u help me out to remove negative marking

Comment: @nischalhada You have 212 reputation, you must be able to post questions?

Comment: I have got low vote for questions multiple zero and -ve vote so that i have got problem

Comment: @nischalhada I upvoted some of your stuff and made an edit to one of your answers. This should help solve the problem. Make sure you approve my edit for an extra +5 reputation. This should allow you to post questions again.

Comment: Thanks dude .. I will help you out in some ways too

Comment: Did you got that dude