# Setting maximum number of characters of `UITextView ` and `UITextField `

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I'd like to set a maximum number of characters allowed to be typed both in a `UITextView` and a `UITextField`. This number will be then shown in a little label (for user's reference, Twitter Style.)

Comment: You are checking the current length of the text, not what the length is about to become.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1773257/4475605

Comment: went on the link I added that code in ViewDidLoad and replaced `UITextField`  with `myMessageObjectLabel ` is it right? Now I got this error Use of undeclared type 'myMessageObjectLabel'. I'm using swift 1.2 at now, could be a problem?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Update **Swift 4.X**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    let numberOfChars = newText.count
    return numberOfChars < 10    // 10 Limit Value
}
```

Try this out:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)
    let numberOfChars = newText.characters.count // for Swift use count(newText)
    return numberOfChars < 10;
}
```

Comment: This is correct but why is the variable named `numberOfLines` when it is the number of characters?

Comment: yes this is correct, i forgot about the number of lines

Comment: @WilliamKinaan What number of lines? There's nothing in the question about limiting the number of lines.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy for pointing out. It was a typo in a rush :-), corrected it now!

Comment: I added this code in `ViewDidLoad` and replaced `textView: UITextView` with `myMessageTextView ` is it right? Now I got this error String does not have a member named 'characters'. I'm using swift 1.2 at now, could be a problem?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my code. For Swift use `count(newText)`. I am using Swift 2.

Comment: Hey ... 1 minute, you said you added my code in `viewDidLoad`? Well thats not correct. In your `viewDidLoad` you would add your view controller as delegate to your `UITextField` something like this `myMessageObjectLabel.delegate = self`. The code that I have shared above is a delegate call back from `UITextField` - add in your class file as an independent function and it should get called back for each character typed in by user in your text field.

Comment: You need to conform to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol. I guess by mistake you added text filed delegate. Please check that out. @biggreentree

Comment: I am sure its very simple stuff. Would it be possible for you to share the project on github? I can take a look. @biggreentree

Comment: Hey, your method signature is totally off. Take a look at my post. You should not use `self.startingMessageTextView `, instead it should be `UITextView`. Use my method word by word. @biggreentree

Comment: you are totally right, I changed it because in my mind I was acting only on that selected  `UITextView` everything works great! thanks I'll do the same on my `UITextField` for object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91487/discussion-between-abhinav-and-biggreentree).

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `return numberOfChars <= 10;` (the less-than symbol should be less-than-or-equal-to)?

Comment: @Abhinav how to restrict the copied text in here? like, clipboard got 2000 characters string where textview allows 1500 character, so when i paste the long string it let the textview empty instead of copying 1500 characters.

Comment: If you want to allow the user to delete chars when they "are over the limit" (can happen if you lower the char limit and user is editing with old (longer text), add a guard...`guard !text.isEmpty else { return true }`

Answer (score 38):

**SWIFT 4**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
     let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
     return newText.count < 10
}
```

Comment: in Swift 4 its: let numberOfChars = newText.count

Comment: @LanceSamaria thanks, updated my answer to Swift 4, since Swift 3 is no longer relative..

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4:**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
  let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
  return newText.count <= 70
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this out:-

```
 func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    print("chars \(textView.text.characters.count) \( text)")

    if(textView.text.characters.count > 20 && range.length == 0) {
        print("Please summarize in 20 characters or less")
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3.0**

Just override this UITextFieldDelegate function, set the desired characterLimit variable and you are good to go:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
{        
        let characterLimit = 5
        let newText = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let numberOfChars = newText.characters.count
        return numberOfChars < characterLimit
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Update for Swift 5

Gives the most forward result

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return range.location < 140 // limit to 140 chars
}
```

Comment: If pasting text is allowed, this will not work

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 , Xcode 9.1 GM

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return textView.text.count + (text.count - range.length) <= 200
}
```

Comment: what's adjust frames for ?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4/ Xcode 9.1**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    let currentText = textView.text ?? ""
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
    let changedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: text)
    return changedText.count <= 399 // Pass your character count here 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 5

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    var newText = textView.text!
    newText.removeAll { (character) -> Bool in
        return character == " " || character == "\n"
    }

    return (newText.count + text.count) <= 40
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding support of pasting text with cutting it by a **maxLength** + avoiding ***UNDO*** action crash:

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if let maxLength = maxLength {
        let maxReplacementLength = min(range.length, maxLength - range.location)
        let replacementRange = NSRange(location: range.location, length: maxReplacementLength)
        let result = NSString(string: (textView.text ?? "")).replacingCharacters(in: replacementRange, with: text)
        
        if result.count <= maxLength && range.length <= maxLength - range.location  {
            return true
        }
        textView.text = String(result[..<result.index(result.startIndex, offsetBy: min(result.count, maxLength))])
        
        return false
    }
    
    return true
}
```