# Swift - Limit the number of characters in lines for UITextview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have the following code to limit the number of lines in UITextView

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

but is there a way to limit the number of characters of each line? how can i set the limit to 50 chars for each line?

**EDIT:**
I tried the solution proposed as possible duplicate but the limit is applied over the entire text, I need to set the limit for each line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting maximum number of characters of \`UITextView \` and \`UITextField \`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935528/setting-maximum-number-of-characters-of-uitextview-and-uitextfield)

Comment: @l'L'l No, I tried this solution but the limits is applied over the entire text, I need to set the limit for each line.

Comment: Alright, vote to close retracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement shouldChangeTextIn and return false if any line has more than the allowed number of characters:

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let maxAllowedCharactersPerLine = 10
        let lines = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text).components(separatedBy: .newlines)
        for line in lines {
            if line.characters.count > maxAllowedCharactersPerLine {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```