# iOS Swift Enable Only Backspace Key in Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview, ios-keyboard-extension

In my app I'm having text limits for some `textView`. For example, In `description` I'm having text limit of 10000. When textView contains more than 10000 character I just need to enable backspace key in keyboard and need to disable all other keys in keyboard, is it possible. Here is my tried code:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText string: String) -> Bool {
    if(textView == DescriptionText)
    {
      if range.length + range.location > (self.DescriptionText.text?.characters.count)!
      {
            return false
      }
      else if range.location == 0 && string == " "
      {
            return false
      }
      let NewLength = (self.DescriptionText.text?.characters.count)! - range.length
      return NewLength <= 9999
      }
      else
      {
          if range.location == 0 && string == " "
          {
                return false
          }
          return true
      }
    }
```

Comment: instead of disabling all other keys you can just prevent typing right?

Comment: NewLength calculation is wrong.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32935626/5523205

Comment: My only problem is I just need to handle in textview contains more than 1000 characters

Comment: That means do u want to stop user to enter more than 1000 characters? Tell me what is the exact purpose of only enabling backspace key, so that it is easy to help u.

Comment: @KrishnarjunBanoth In above code I can able to stop user do not enter more than 10000 character. My exact purpose is previously we not have text limit there so some user may have more than 10000 characters there. If it is more than 10000 characters I only want users to use backspace key in keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In textfieldShouldChange add the following:

```
if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    return newLength <= 10000;
```

Answer (score -1):

I m not sure what you want exactly but you can prevent user typing more than 10000 characters in textView using below lines.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText string: String) -> Bool {

    let textString = (textView.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if textView == self.DescriptionText && string.characters.count > 0 {
        return textString.characters.count <= 10000 
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: @down-voters if you explain something for down voting i will correct myself if it's wrong.