# Set maximum length to dynamically added textfields

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have added textfields dynamically to scrollview as below:-

```
for(int i = 0; i< responseBillPay.billerDetails.payeeFormat.count; i++) {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, width, height)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    textField.placeholder = [responseBillPay.billerDetails.payeeFormat[i] name];
    textField.delegate = self;
  [innerScroll addSubview:textField];
}
```

Now i want to set maximum length to each textfield.How could I do this?
I got the  response of webservice as :-

```
payeeFormat =         
          (

         {

            displayFlag = false;
            length = 4;
            name = "BU(Billing Unit)";
            validation = "Please enter 4 digits BU(Billing Unit)";
        },
                    {
            displayFlag = false;
            length = 2;
            name = "PC(Processing Cycle)";
            validation = "Please enter only numbers in PC(Processing Cycle),PC(Processing Cycle) should be maximum 2 digits,PC(Processing Cycle) should be minimum 1 digit";
        },
                    {
            displayFlag = true;
            length = 12;
            name = "Consumer No.";
            validation = "Consumer No. should be maximum 12 digits,Consumer No. should be minimum";
        }
    );
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it dynamic little bit according to you. like text range or placeholder text etc

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString * searchStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSString *placeHOlder = textField.placeholder;

    if ([placeHOlder isEqualToString:@"BU(Billing Unit)"]) {
        if ([searchStr length] <= 4) {
            return YES;
        }
        else
            return NO;
    }
    else 
        return NO;
}
```

**2nd Way**

You can store all textfield in a array and you can check that text field in the above delegate method. If it is equal then put your text range and return `YES` otherwise return `NO`.

Comment: response varies according to request so I cant comapre the textfield placeholder as in some cases it there may be 1 textfield in other 3 as it is.

Comment: In that you can use my 2nd way that will work perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can also subclass UITextField and add the attributes that you care about directly to the subclass as properties according to your payee response.