# How to move cursor in UITextField (Swift 2.1)

Tags: ios, swift2

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `UITextField` has never (publicly) had a `setSelectedRange:` method. `UITextView` has a `setSelectedRange:` method (in Objective-C). Are you trying to set the selected range of a `UITextField` or of a `UITextView`?

Comment: Possible duplicated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412115/limit-length-of-multiple-uitextfields-in-swift-2

Comment: @robmayoff true, might be so, but still I need this to work on UITextField

Comment: @EBDOKUM hello why do you want to move cursor. do you want user to start typing from certain position?

Comment: @hellosheikh I just want to keep "%" symbol after the number that the user enters at all times

Comment: oh okay so you have a textfield filled with default value "%" and when user start types it'll be like this 

"hello%" right ? @EBDOKUM

Comment: @hellosheikh I added a Target for all Editing events - it calls a method, which takes the text inside of the field, and puts the "%" symbol to the end. But that doesn't work that great because if the cursor gets behind this last symbol, there is no way to delete it and therefore I have to move it manually. And that is exactly what happens when I first tap the field. What I wanted to do is to add a method, which would always put the cursor second from the end.

Answer (score 1):

UITextField conforms to UITextInput. This means that you can set its `selectedTextRange` property (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInput/selectedTextRange). A range with zero length is the cursor alone.