# Limit the number of Characters for an IBOutlet TextView, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextview, viewcontroller, iboutlet

hopefully someone can guide me and help me out here!!

I'm retrieving some characters data from an API and I have stored the value in an `IBOutlet` type of `UITextView` named `UITextDisplay`. All I'm trying to do is display 300 characters from that data or either less, but for some reason isn't letting me.

Thank you in advance!!

I also delegate the `UITextField` to the `ViewController` so it should work and my code compile perfectly fine. The

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate
{
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
    {
        textView.text = UITextDisplay.text

        let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

        return newText.count < 300

    }
}
```

Also.. is there any way to remove from the characters the end of it "+2637 characters"??
[image]

Look forward to any resolution!
Amaury,

Comment: So you want to set a limit of MAX 300 characters in the textView?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the maximum character length of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield) (In my answer you can also see for UITextView)

Comment: @Hitesh Tried.,. but it didn't worked! At this point I'm just figuring out if I'm calling it properly... :/

Comment: Exactly..@AbhishekPatel

Comment: @AmauryC. To use this extension, You need to remove delegate eqaul to self(Your current UIViewController). That's it

Comment: @Hitesh Thank you for your prompt response! So you want to remove the UITextView Delegate  itself from the current ViewController??  You mentioned UIViewController.. but I created an extension from the ViewController, not the UIViewController. I'm a bit confused right now. Could you please elaborate your answer for me please? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look of below question

[Set the maximum character length of a UITextField (In my answer you can also see for UITextView)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540090/5036586)

Instead of writing duplicate code everywhere, You can create an extension of `UITextView` or `UITextField` to set the max length

## Update:

**Comment Explanation:**

First thing, You need to remove the `UITextView` delegate method from your current view controller. Because extension of `UITextView` is internally used `UITextViewDelegate`

**Note:** Delegate is one to one communication. In your case, if you implement delegate in the current view controller then an extension of `UITextView` is not worked.

Comment: There should be a shorter an answer for this, but thank you! @hitesh

Comment: thank you so much!! I really appreciated your time and explanation! Merry Christmas!!