# How do I create custom class for maximum text length of UITextfield using protocol extension?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have created a protocol with extension and set the the textfield method properly but when I created the custom class ,
I fetched the  value but not able to send back to the protocol.

```
protocol Limiter {
    var  limit : Int {get set}
}
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let tf = textField.text ?? ""
        guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: tf) else { return false }

              // add their new text to the existing text
              let updatedText = tf.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

              print(updatedText)
        return updatedText.count  <= (textField as! Limiter).limit
     }

}
```

```
//Custom class 
class TextFieldLimiter: UITextField , Limiter{
    var limit: Int = 0

 @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
   get {
    print(limit)
     return limit
   }
   set {
     limit = newValue
    print(limit)
   }
 }   
}
```

I tried this code and am not sure I'm doing correctly or not.

So, please help me out...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield/29804183#29804183

Comment: Yes , but when I tried that option it partly works for me... If I try to paste some big text then it allows me... I want to allow to paste only the text whose limit is less or equal to my maximum length .. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to be found in the web, depending on your usage

The best would be to use the `UITextFieldDelegate`  protocol, esp. `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`:

- You could let your subclass `TextFieldLimiter` implement the delegate and handle the protocol method there.

  - But this only works if there are no other delegates set, because there can be only one.
- You could implement the delegate on the view controller and check if the *sender* is a `TextFieldLimiter` and check the limits there

  - This would lead to repeated code
  - But you could delegate from there to a to-be-written `validate` function that you would implement in `TextFieldLimiter`

You could also try this in your subclass `TextFieldLimiter` without using the delegate, for example override `override func canPerformAction`  and check if it's the paste action and then check if the paste buffer is too big or not to allow the action or not. But this is a litte more tricky, and you have to also consider the *undo* case.