# Displays a alert if more characters are entered in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to display the same warning as in the picture when entering over the allowed number of characters. This happens on import without any other action.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpoJy.jpg)

Here is my code to limit characters:

```
 private func textLimit(existingText: String?, newText: String, limit: Int) -> Bool {
        let text = existingText ?? ""
        let isAtLimit = text.count + newText.count <= limit
        return isAtLimit
    }
```

and delegate:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return self.textLimit(existingText: textField.text, newText: string, limit: 5)
    }
```

I have found the solution:

```
   private func textLimit(existingText: String?, newText: String, limit: Int) -> Bool {
        let text = existingText ?? ""
        let limitText = text.count + newText.count
        let isAtLimit = text.count + newText.count <= limit
        if limitText > limit {
            var alert: UIAlertController!
            alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Character limit exceeded", preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        return isAtLimit
    }
```

But how can I automatically break the trailing characters when pasting a string? And when you put the cursor somewhere to add text, the redundant character will be replaced?
Hope everyone understand the question, sorry my english is not good!

Comment: Your code for limiting characters looks okay; is it? If so, where's the part about the alert?

Comment: See this for an implementation of the text field delegate method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield/1773257#1773257

Answer (score 0):

This kind of alert seems like a Toast. There's an open source iOS library called [Toast-Swift](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift) that produces this kind of alert. Install it on your project and then just before the return of the `textField:shouldCharactersIn:replacementString:` method you can call the component to display an alert:

```swift
self.view.makeToast("Character limit exceeded.")
```

You can check the component docs for more advanced customization of this dialog.

Comment: Take a look at how the library shows the alert and try to reproduce it in your code so.